# wp_enqueue_script() not loading multiple scripts

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to load two scripts through the wp_enqueue_script(). I made to functions but only the first loads not the second one. Here is the code:

```
//Load my own jQuery
function fix_noconflict() {
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery' , 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js' );}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' , 'fix_noconflict' );

//This two functions follow the same
function mauricio_bootstrap_script_jquery() {

//Includes bootstrap jQuery
wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri().'/mauricio_bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

//This enqueus  the script

wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}   
// Adds the new bootstrap function to the wp_enqueue_scripts
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mauricio_bootstrap_script_jquery' );

function mauricio_bootstrap_script_carousel() {

wp_register_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri().'/mauricio_bootstrap/js/bootstrap-carousel.js', array( 'jquery' ) );


wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'mauricio_bootstrap_script_carousel' );
```

Just for the record I have wp_head() in my header. And as I said it loads the first function that includes bootstrap.js.

Thanks,

M

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why don´t you try to put all your functions inside a main function, like this?

```
function wpEnqueueScripts(){
    // Adds the new bootstrap function to the wp_enqueue_scripts
    wp_register_script('custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/mauricio_bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-script');

    // Adds the new bootstrap function to the wp_enqueue_scripts
    wp_register_script('myscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/mauricio_bootstrap/js/bootstrap-carousel.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('myscript');
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpEnqueueScripts');
```

Answer (score 2):

Someone at the wordpress forum provided this. The two functions were combined and when adding the action the use of the 'template_redirect' $tag is used instead of the 'wp_enqueue_script'

```
function mauricio_bootstrap_scripts() {
wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri().'/mauricio_bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );

wp_register_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri().'/mauricio_bootstrap/js/bootstrap-carousel.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript' );
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'mauricio_bootstrap_scriptsl' );
```